# how to connect a 240v heater with 2 black/1 green wires on one side and a black and a red, a white and a green on the other side

Tags: wiring

I have a stelpro heater 240v to install. The wires from the wall are also 240v (tested). 2 black wires and one green are coming out from the heater. The 4 wires from the wall are one red, one black, one copper, one white. Which wires do I connect to what? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Heaters usually do not need the white(neutral) wire.

Can usually just put a wire nut on the white wire and not use it.

One black to black, one black to red, and green/bare to green/bare.